# Как на практике применить MVC в Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, mvc

Не судите строго, я начинающий программист в Unity3d. Пока делал простые проекты не было необходимости пользоваться шаблонами проектирования. На данном этапе не могу разобраться с практическими этапами MVC в Unity3d. Сам принцип понятен, но возникают вопросы на практике. Как применять этот шаблон.
Например:
У меня есть персонаж с перенесенными HP, MovementSpeed e.t.. У меня есть скрипты Movement(), Jump() e.t.. Есть еще переменные которые отображают currentHP e.t.. Как мне это все связать?

Comment: Если вы не находите, как применить данный шаблон проектирования к вашей "модели", то скорее всего он вам не нужен!. Потому, что - шаблон проектирования нужно подбирать по вашим запросам, а не наоборот. мне кажется в unity будет лучше применить компонентный подход в смешку с синглтонами (но это не про большие проекты)

Comment: На данный момент, моя задача понять как это использовать на практике, чтобы в случае нужды в нем, было понятно как его использовать.

Comment: ну тогда применение `MVC` будет бредом. В роли модели у вас выступит сам персонаж со всеми его полями (жизни, скорость и т.д.). В роли контроллера у вас будлет все, что он может делать (например реализована функция прыжка). В роли представляения выступит тоже контролер, но этот контролер будет знать что отображать в той или инной ситуации. Ну как-то так

Comment: вот [статья с хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/281783/)

Comment: Ну, не знаю. MV паттерны, это когда есть строго органиченая модель, строго ограниченое представление и посредник. В юнити намного проще обойтись без этих приблуд, т. к. вся работа в бехэвиоре (скрипте) в юнити - это работа с компонентами. А компонент - это ни модель, ни представление (ну, разве что кроме отдельных исключений). Модель - это когда объект <-> байты. Тут этого нет. Представление - это когда  объект -> UI. Тут во время runtime'а можно что-то подобное мутить, да и то в коком-нибудь аниматоре... MVC в юнити - спорное решение.